# Different behavior of Clear in different versions of Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, syntax, clear

Consider the following code:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3};
m = 17;

{list1, m} // Clear
```

In Mathematica 13.2, this syntax with `Clear` works without problems. In Mathematica 13.1, it returns error:

> Clear::ssym: {list1, m} is not a symbol or a string.

What is an alternative of the syntax that allows to apply `Clear` to all the elements of some list of variables?

I have already tried `Clear[##] & @@ {list1, m}` to convert it to the standard form `Clear[list1,m]`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're using is a syntax added and well-documented in version 13.2. (Legacy document is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13.2/ref/Clear.html), you can click the UPDATED button to see what's updated. )

In earlier version, you need to control the evaluation order a bit:

```
Clear /@ Unevaluated@{list1, m};
```

Your code can be fixed, too:

```
Function[, Clear[##], HoldAll] @@ Unevaluated@{list1, m}
```

Notice we need to stop evaluation twice, one for `Apply`(`@@`) using `Unevaluated`, one for `Function` (`&`) using `HoldAll` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Try this workaround for V 13.1

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3};
m = 17;
Unprotect[Clear];
SetAttributes[Clear, {Listable}];
Protect[Clear];
Clear[{list1, m}];
```

No error and clears the symbols.  Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It looks like something that was fixed in later versions of Mathematica.